# Gaussian likelihood + which prior = Gaussian Marginal?

Tags: normal-distribution, mixed-model, prior, marginal-distribution, conjugate-prior

Given a Gaussian likelihood for a sample $y$ like $$p(y|\theta) = \mathcal{N}(y;\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))$$ with $\Theta$ being the parameter space and $\mu(\theta)$, $\Sigma(\theta)$ arbitrary parameterisations of the mean vector and the covariance matrix.

**Is it possible to specify a prior density $p(\theta)$ and parameterisation of the mean vector $\mu(\theta)$ and the covariance matrix $\Sigma(\theta)$ such that the marginal likelihood $$p(y)=\int_{\theta\in\Theta}N(y;\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))p(\theta)d\theta$$ is a Gaussian likelihood?**

I guess excluding the trivial solution that the covariance is known, that is, $\Sigma(\theta)=\Sigma$, where $\Sigma$ is an arbitrary fixed covariance matrix, this is not possible.

For the special case $\mu(\sigma^2)=\mu$ and $\Sigma(\sigma^2)=\sigma^2$, that is $y$ is one-dimensional, and $p(\sigma^2)=\mathcal{U}(\sigma^2;a,b)$, where $\mathcal{U}(\sigma^2;a,b)$ denotes the uniform density  I can show it: 
\begin{align} 
p(y)&=\int_0^\infty \mathcal{N}(y;\mu,\sigma^2)\mathcal{U}(\sigma^2;a,b)d\sigma^2 \\
&= \frac{1}{b-a} \underbrace{\int_a^b \mathcal{N}(y;\mu,\sigma^2)}_\text{not a Gaussian density}
\end{align}

The accepted answer contains a formal or informal proof or pointers to it.

Answer (score 3):

Your conjecture seems to be true: only a constant variance can lead to
a normal margin. My proof is limited to the case where the
expectation $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ is known, and hence can be assumed to
be zero. For the general case, more sophisticated arguments from
functional analysis seem to be required.

Note that the question is actually about *continuous mixture of normals* as well
as about Bayes. The statement proved here it that a (continuous) *scale
mixture* of normals can be normal only for a trivial mixture.

First consider the case of a one-dimensional normal with known mean
$\mu = 0$ and precision parameter $\omega := 1 / \Sigma >0$. Without loss of
generality, we can assume that the parameter $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is
the precision $\omega$ itself. If the marginal distribution of $y$ is
normal, then $\int \exp\{-y^2 \omega / 2\}\,\omega^{1/2}
p(\omega)\,\text{d}\omega$ is a normal density up to a multiplicative
constant. This density being an even function of $y$ must take the
form $c\exp\{ -y^2 \omega_0 / 2\}$ for some $\omega_0 >0$ and some
constant $c >0$. Since this holds for any $y$ we get with $s := y^2$
$$ \int_0^\infty \exp\{-s \omega \,/ 2\}\,\omega^{1/2}
p(\omega)\text{d}\omega = c \exp\{ -s \omega_0 \,/ 2\} $$ for all $s
\geq 0$, which shows that the finite measure with density function
$\omega \mapsto \omega^{1/2} p(\omega)$ is proportional to the Dirac
mass at $\omega_0$ because these two measures have the same Laplace
transform, up to a multiplicative constant. Thus $\omega$ is almost
surely (a.s.) equal to $\omega_0$.

This proof extends to the
$d$-dimensional normal with mean zero and precision matrix
$\boldsymbol{\Omega}:=\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1}$. The margin then writes
as $\propto \int \exp\{-\mathbf{y}^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}\,\mathbf{y} \,/
2\}\,
\left|\boldsymbol{\Omega}\right|^{1/2}p(\boldsymbol{\Omega})\,\text{d}\boldsymbol{\Omega}$
where the integral is on the set $\mathcal{P}$ of positive definite
symmetric $d \times d$ matrices. If this integral is identical to
$c\exp\{ -\mathbf{y}^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_0 \mathbf{y} / 2\}$,
then by taking $\mathbf{y}:= \sqrt{s} \,\boldsymbol{u}$ for a scalar
$s \geq 0$ and an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{u}$, we find as above that
$\mathbf{u}^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}\, \mathbf{u}$ must be a.s. equal
to $\mathbf{u}^\top \boldsymbol{\Omega}_0 \mathbf{u}$, which shows
that $\boldsymbol{\Omega}$ is a.s. equal to $\boldsymbol{\Omega}_0$.
The proof works even if the measure conveniently written as having
density $|\boldsymbol{\Omega}|^{1/2} p(\boldsymbol{\Omega})$
concentrates on a subset of $\mathcal{P}$ with Lebesgue measure zero,
because the Laplace transform argument still applies. So the proof
works for a general parameterisation of the precision (or variance)
matrix.

Comment: I have not understood your proof fully yet. In comparison to Jacky1's answer it seems relatively complex. What do you think about his proof?

Comment: Well I could not understand how the prior can depend of $y$ in Jacky's
answer. Yet his statement as I understand it is wrong - I did the same
error first:) Indeed, $\mu$ is not necessarily constant and if
the variance is constant, $\mu$ still can be normal which is easily
checked by completing a square. I now have a proof for the independent prior case (one-dimensional for simplicity), and hope to write it down soon, maybe as a new answer.  The variance $\Sigma$ must be constant and $\mu$ must be normal (possibly degenerate).

Comment: Could you expand your reasoning in the paragraph starting with "Since this holds for any $y$ and ending with "(a.s.) equal to $ω_0$"? Maybe with pointers to the theorems you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are a priori independent and that $y$
has a normal margin with mean $\mu_0$ and variance $\Sigma_0$. I
will prove that then the variance $\Sigma$ must be constant, and
the mean $\mu$ must have a normal prior (possibly degenerate).

I will stick to the one-dimensional case for simplicity, using the
characteristic function (c.f.) of $y$, i.e. $\phi_y(t) := 
\mathbb{E}[e^{yit}]$.  We know that $\phi_y(t) = \exp\{\mu_0 it - \Sigma_0 t^2 /2$} and
 a similar formula holds for the distribution of $y$ conditional on $\mu$
and $\Sigma$, which is normal by assumption. So for any real $t$ 
$$
 \mathbb{E}[e^{yit}] = \int \mathbb{E}\left[e^{yit} \, \vert \,\mu,\,\Sigma\right]\,
 p(\mu) p(\Sigma)
 \,\text{d}\mu \text{d} \Sigma =
 \int \exp\left\{ \mu it  - \Sigma t^2/2 \right\} \,p(\mu) p(\Sigma)
 \,\text{d}\mu \text{d}\Sigma, 
$$
and by rearranging the integral, we must have
$$
   \exp\left\{ \mu_0 it - \Sigma_0 t^2 /2 \right\} = 
 \left[\int \exp\left\{ \mu it \right\} p(\mu) 
 \,\text{d}\mu \right]
 \left[\int \exp\left\{ -\Sigma t^2/2\right\} p(\Sigma) 
 \,\text{d}\Sigma \right].
$$
The assumptions needed for such a rearrangement are easily checked.

The first integral at right hand side, say $\phi_1(t)$, is the c.f. of
$\mu$. Note that since $\phi_1(t) e^{-\mu_0 it}$ is found to be real, we see that
the distribution of $\mu$ is symmetric w.r.t. $\mu_0$, and hence that
$\mathbb{E}[\mu] = \mu_0$, as it might have been anticipated.

Now it turns out that the second integral at right hand side, say
$\phi_2(t)$, is also a c.f. To see that, we must check that $\phi_2(0)
= 1$, that $\phi_2$ is continuous at $t=0$ and also that the function
$\phi_2$ is positive definite (p.d.). The first requirement is
obvious, the second is proved by dominated convergence. Now turn to
the p.d. requirement: if the prior distribution written as
$p(\Sigma)\text{d}\Sigma$ is a Dirac mass, then $\phi_2$ is
p.d. because $\phi_2$ is then the c.f. of a normal distribution.  If
the prior is a discrete mixture of Dirac masses, this is true as well
since $\phi_2$ then is the c.f. of a mixture of normals. By a continuity
argument, we see that $\phi_2$ is p.d.

Now let us use the powerful *Lévy-Cramér theorem* which tells that
both functions $\phi_j$ for $j=1$, $2$ must take the form $\exp\{a_j i t -
b_jt^2 /2 \}$ with $a_j$ real and $b_j \geq 0$. So $\mu$
must be normal (possibly degenerate) with mean $a_1 = \mu_0$.
By simple algebra we then have
$$
    \exp\{ -(\Sigma_0 - b_1) t^2 /2 \} = \int_0^\infty \exp\{ - \Sigma t^2 /2\} p(\Sigma)
    \, \text{d} \Sigma 
$$
which holds for any real $t$. Since any non-negative real writes as $t^2/2$, we see that
the Laplace transform of the prior of $\Sigma$ must be equal to that
of the Dirac mass at $\Sigma_0 - b_1$ and we are done.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. It will take me some time to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a proposition of proof for you, but you need to check it.

Assume that the marginal likelihood is Gaussian :

$p(y)=\mathcal{N}(y,m,\Gamma)$

then the prior density can be defined by

$p(\theta)=\mathcal{N}(y,\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))^{-1}\mathcal{N}(y,m,\Gamma)f(\theta)$

where $f$ checks $\int_{\theta\in\Theta}f(\theta)d\theta =1$ and $f(\theta)\geq 0$ for $\theta\in\Theta$. ($f(\theta)$ is $p(\theta|y)$).

To be a density, the integral of the prior density $p(\theta)$ on $\Theta$ has to be equal to 1. 
In other words,

$\int_{\theta\in\Theta}\mathcal{N}(y,\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))^{-1}\mathcal{N}(y,m,\Gamma)f(\theta)d\theta =1$.

It leads to

$\int_{\theta\in\Theta}\mathcal{N}(y,\mu(\theta),\Sigma(\theta))^{-1}\mathcal{N}(y,m,\Gamma)f(\theta)d\theta = \int_{\theta\in\Theta}f(\theta)d\theta$

This equality being true if and only if $\mu(\theta)=m$ and $\Sigma(\theta)=\Gamma$.

Comment: I like the proof idea. I am pretty certain that all steps but the last one are valid. Surely the integral of two functions are the same if the functions are the same but this is not a necessary condition. Are you using a different theorem there?

Comment: If you replace $p(\theta|y)$ with its defintion via bayes in your first formula for $p(\theta)$, then it becomes $p(\theta)=p(\theta)$. Surely, nothing follows from this inequality.